# gstreamer and vhs capture: video ok, but sound mute

Tags: gstreamer

With this script

```
#!/bin/sh
videodevice="/dev/video0"
alsadevice="hw:2,0"

gst-launch-1.0 -q v4l2src device="$videodevice" do-timestamp=true norm="PAL" pixel-aspect-ratio=1 \
    ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,framerate=25/1,width=720,height=576 \
    ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 \
    ! mux. \
  alsasrc device="$alsadevice" do-timestamp=true \
    ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=48000,channels=2 \
    ! queue \
  max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 \
    ! mux. matroskamux name=mux \
    ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 \
    ! filesink location=vhs.mkv
```

The video is ok, but audio is mute.
I have checked with alsamixer and pavucontrol and audio capture volume is OK.
With mencoder audio works fine using the options

```
forceaudio:immediatemode=0
```

Something similar with gstreamer?

Comment: I have had a lot of issues with the sound using gstreamer. I downloaded Parole instead and have no issues with it.

Comment: Probably some cards has not complete support in gstreamer, with ivtv this script don't work even for video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: before launch gstreamer the card must be "unmute" with this command.

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl mute=0
```